# SharePoint - SOAP Request To Web Services Returns List Of Operations

Tags: sharepoint, soap, vbscript, sharepoint-2013

I have a VB script that is supposed to grab a specific list item from SharePoint 2013 via web services.

Relevant code:

```
Dim response, request, colItem, objItem
Dim fileSystem: Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
request = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" & _
"  <soap:Body>" & _
"    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>" & _
"      <listName>{FC3E18D6-33E5-4032-BE4B-F0F92F6F18BA}</listName>" + _
"      <viewName>{2861DF9F-11F8-4E4B-A318-D4D37C1C5169}</viewName>" + _
"      <query></query>" & _
"    </GetListItems>" & _
"  </soap:Body>" & _
"</soap:Envelope>"

http.open "POST", "http://<redacted>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(request)
http.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems"
http.send request
```

However, it is just returning the same page that I see if I navigate directly to .../_vti_bin/Lists.asmx, which is the list of supported operations. If I click on "GetListItems", the example XML it provides looks like what I have in the VB script, except for a few parameters which I believe are optional:

```
POST /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: <redacted>
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>string</listName>
      <viewName>string</viewName>
      <query>string</query>
      <viewFields>string</viewFields>
      <rowLimit>string</rowLimit>
      <queryOptions>string</queryOptions>
      <webID>string</webID>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have Googled around and been unable to find what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GUID try using the regular names of the list and views for the listName and viewName XML elements.

```
 <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <listName>My List</listName>
  <viewName>All Items</viewName>
 </GetListItems>
```

Here's a sample code I used on my SP 2013 site with jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
  url: "https://site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
  data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Body> <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> <listName>My Test Cases</listName>  </GetListItems> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (msg) {
   console.log(msg);
  },
  error: function (data, status, error) {
   console.log('error');
  }
  });
```